# why can't web site not accessible using port 83?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have hosted site to windows server  2012 r2.
I have bind site by port 81,83,2163.
It is accessible using all other port except port 83 using domain name as well as
with IP, but when I'm accessing using port 83 with domain name it is not accessible, but it is 
accessible using IP with port 83.

I have disable firewall still not working, why?

**Edited**
[image]

Comment: It is not recommended to run on such a low port range because some ports are used by other services/tools: http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ip/ports00000.htm

Comment: If the site works via domain name to all ports other than 83, I would suspect some sort of misconfiguration relating to host binding through host headers; eg the domain name is not actually bound to port 83 within IIS.

Comment: @DavidW, I have added site binding screen above is there any problem with this?

Comment: @DavinTryon, but it is working on another server with same port and same IIS settings..!

Comment: @Kaishu I didn't say it *couldn't* work, I said it is not *recommended* to do it that way. :)

Comment: @DavinTyrun, I understand, but why it is not working on this server by using domain name.?

Comment: You need to map the domain name as the "Host Name" in the bindings configuration.

Comment: @DavidW, I have tried by mapping domain name as "Host Name" also try to bind only specific ID instead of allowing all, but still not working..!

Answer (score 0):

From the Bindings list, select the Port 83 binding, and click "Edit." From the dialog, specify the fully-qualified domain name for the site in question as the "host name." This allows IIS to respond to the request for the website via the desired domain name reference.